# Is there way to define processing extent in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, extents, qgis-processing

Is it possible to define the extent of a processing tool, like it is in the "Environments" in ArcGIS? For example "Same as Display, or "Same as Layer..".

Comment: I think only certain algorithms have the option to set extent as per [this](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/extents.html) link.

Comment: Tnx! At the moment i am using a scratch layer and a clip before processing as workaround. For example for contouring a defined region out of a big dhm.