# Is there any way to set a processing extent for QGIS:Voronoipolygon?

Tags: qgis, extents, qgis-processing, voronoi-thiessen

I was playing around with the QGIS:voronoipolygons command line function from QGIS and noticed that there was no option for setting the processing extent. This causes QGIS to pick the minimum extent i.e. the voronoi calculation stops at the south/north/west/easternmost points.

However, I need this boundary to extend beyond this point. For this I need to set the processing extent. Does anyone know if this is possible within Qgis?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144985/

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I'm also looking for a way to use a polygon as extent instead of lower lefter and upper right.