# How to split polygon with multiple points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am working on spliting a polygon which includes multiple points.

I tried it manually but due to the large dataset it is very time consuming.

Are there any automated tools or plugins to do that?

I wanted to split polygon which includes the point (Multiple Location).

The final output will be a polygon for each point.

[image]

Comment: split means 'divide'. Can you elaborate in your workflow? What's your expected output?

Comment: split polygon which having more than one points
so i will get each polygon for each point after spatial joining on the polygon shape file

Comment: First step could be to create Voronoi polygons http://djjr-courses.wikidot.com/soc128:qgis-voronoi-polygons.

Comment: Any other steps. i tried with Voronoi polygons but i am editing zip town borders( polygons) and Address (Points). i want polygon for each address that i will get after spatial join. Voronoi cant give me the exact zip borders.

Comment: @user30184 has a good suggestion, but in your case it would (might) require being able to use a processing extent as recently asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145034/ (with no answer). At the same time, this might be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135929/ if that method/solution would work for you. Otherwise it would be helpful if you could say *how* you want to split them up - does it matter how big they are, is there a value or other attribute of the point that relates to size or area?

Comment: nearly 1000 polygon having more than 2 addresses so i wanted to split that polygon and make single polygon for each address. Area is very large so it will be taking lot of time for manual splitting. I have tried manual splitting but how can i judge it is exact. its manual splitting so it might have some errors